# R two digit year into four

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Stumped on easiest way to append a current year column (only has last two digits 21, 22, 23) to include first two digits (in this case only "20"). I've tried str_glue and past0("20", variable) but had no luck. Any functions/help would be super appreciated. Also, the current year column is in a character type, not a date currently.

`test <- tibble(rep= "John Smith", quarter= "q2", year= 19:23, ideal_year= 2019:2023) %>%  mutate(year=as.character(year))`

Comment: Typo, it's `paste0('20', c(21, 22, 23))`.

Comment: Please provide some reproducible example. 
BTW, paste0("20", variable) would do the work - unless your typo is by accident.

Comment: `paste0("20", variable)` and then `as.numeric` should work. Please show your wok and output more clearly.

Comment: Hi- i've added sample code above! Sorry about that!

Comment: `%>% mutate(year = as.integer(paste0("20", year)))` works for me. If you're having problems with that, then please share the code that fails and the specific error. Also, it's just a year; if you want a `Date`-class object, should we assume that you want (for instance) `"2019-01-01"`?

Comment: `test %>% mutate( year = as.numeric(paste0("20", year)))` does actually work. Please show what you have tried and your output and please specify what you want to do more clearly!

Comment: Thanks team! I originally had paste0 inputed incorrectly, it works correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way seems to be:

```
tibble(rep= "John Smith", year= 19:23, ideal_year= 2019:2023) %>% 
    mutate(
        year = year + 2000
    )
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  rep         year ideal_year
  <chr>      <dbl>      <int>
1 John Smith  2019       2019
2 John Smith  2020       2020
3 John Smith  2021       2021
4 John Smith  2022       2022
5 John Smith  2023       2023
```